# coco2d game update

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In coco2d game, update function is call every 1/60 of second.

```
    this.scheduleUpdate();

update: function (dt) { }
```

The score Label is

```
  var scoreLabel = cc.LabelTTF.create("0", "fantasy", 20, cc.size(0, 0), cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT);
    scoreLabel.setPosition(cc.p(winSize.width - 80, winSize.height));
    scoreLabel.schedule(function () {
        var showingScore = parseInt(scoreLabel.getString());
        if (showingScore < b2.getUserScore()) {
            scoreLabel.setString((showingScore + 5)
                .toString());
        }
    });
    this.addChild(scoreLabel, 5);
```

How often is the scoreLabel being updated?  How do you setup a timer to update every 2 seconds for the scoreLabel?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a schedule for this :

```
-(void) schedule:  @SEL(selector)  interval:  ccTime  ;
```

selector : your function that you want to update .
interval : time interval between each update .

you could once initialize Label then in a function (for example "Update Label") change it's
attributes .